# Cannot access Mosca mqtt broker deployed on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, mosca

```js
const express    = require('express');
const helmet     = require('helmet');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan     = require('morgan');
const path       = require('path');
const server     = require('./modules/server');
const dashboard  = require('./modules/dashboard');
const config = require('./config');
const routes = require('./routes');

const app  = express();

app.use(helmet()); // secure http communication middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('tiny')); // http request logger
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
const mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, server);
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);

/**
 * Mosca Server Settings below
 */
var mosca = require('mosca');
var http = require('http');
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);

var moscaSettingss = {
  type: 'mongo',
  url: 'mongodb://***:31157/mqtt',
  pubsubCollection: 'pub_sub',
  mongo: {}
};

httpServer= new mosca.Server({
  backend: moscaSettingss,
  persistence: {
    factory: mosca.persistence.Mongo,
    url: 'mongodb://***:31157/mqtt'
  }
}, function() {
  httpServer.attachHttpServer(app);
});

httpServer.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Mosca is running');
});

httpServer.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
  console.log('client connected', client.id);
});

httpServer.on('published', function(packet, client) {
  console.log('Published : ', packet.payload);
});

httpServer.on('subscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('subscribed : ', topic);
});

httpServer.on('unsubscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('unsubscribed : ', topic);
});

httpServer.on('clientDisconnecting', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnecting : ', client.id);
});

httpServer.on('clientDisconnected', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnected : ', client.id);
});

/**
 * End of Mosca Server Settings
 */

app.listen(config.server.port, () => {
  console.log(`Magic happens on port ${config.server.port}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

I have made an express app, which contains mosca mqtt broker. Some how I cannot connect to that mqtt. Tried all possible urls.

In the express app, I made a mqtt client, which sucessfully connects with the broker. But out side Heroku, my devices are unable to connect.

Awaiting response.

Comment: This might help https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/issues/392

Comment: @Molda I tried this, but not worked.

Comment: Without seeing any code it's really hard to tell where the problem is. Can you add to your question how you setup mosca and express?

Comment: @Molda I added source file please take a look. This code works if a make a mqtt client in this app. but out of this heroku server, I cant connect with the broker.

Comment: one more thing how do you connect from client?

Comment: @Molda I used **mqttfx** utility, MQTT Lense (a chrome browser utility), also tried from a local ExpressJs app 

const client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://mevris-cloud.herokuapp.com:1883');

Comment: Then try ws://mevris-cloud.herokuapp.com:80

Comment: @Molda wow... i spent almost 6 hours. you *ws://mevris-cloud.herokuapp.com:80* worked. Thanks

Comment: Cool. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @Molda plz post this as an answer, so I will mark it correct.

Comment: @Molda now the same code is not working. this is so frustrating. my client keeps trying to connect with broker and on every request the broker my broker, which is in a expressjs app, shows following log
`2016-10-26T14:14:26.654034+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mevris-cloud.herokuapp.com request_id=daee6024-297a-4562-b575-1eb0a0410524 fwd="172.20.2.81,125.209.73.246" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=378
` but client does not connect.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku will not open the port necessary for MQTT. This is why express can access it locally but none of your devices can.

Answer (score 0):

I also try ws://mevris-cloud.herokuapp.com:80. It works!